# compare user input to list of key words

Tags: python

I want to take user input and compare it to a list of key words through a function, if any of the words input by the user match a key word, the condition is met and breaks the loop. If none of the words match a key word, then the console asks for input again. I have been manipulating this loop and have either gotten it to continuously ask for input no matter if a key word is met or validate every word input. Any advice on how to correct it would be great appreciated.

```
def validated_response(user_complaint):
    valid_list = user_complaint.split()

    while True:
           if user_complaint == "stop":
                    break
           for valid in valid_list:
                    if valid.lower() not in user_complaint.lower():
                           print("Response not recognized, please try again")
                           input("Enter response: ")
                           continue

                    else:
                           print("response validated: ")
            break
        return True
```

Comment: There are a few issues with your example: the second line is not correctly indented, perhaps you should consider using a standard indent of 4 and reindent the code. Also, you're providing a function, but you're not showing how you expect to call it. And finally, the input is not captured, currently your code is just comparing the split parts of user_complaints to its characters, which is likely not what you're after.

Comment: I edited the indentation. I coded it to get user_complaint on a different module, import this function to that module and then calling a main function that calls this function. I was trying to split the different words input by a user and then compare each of those words to all of the words in my list key_words.

Answer (score 0):

This function will continue getting user input until the input matches "kwrd1", "kwrd2", or "kwrd3":

```
def get_input():
    keywords = ['kwrd1', 'kwrd2', 'kwrd3']
    user_input = None
    while True:
        user_input = input()
        if user_input in keywords:
            break
    return user_input
```

If you are matching it against a python keyword, there is a builtin `keyword` module:

```
import keyword

def get_input():
    user_input = None
    while True:
        user_input = input()
        if keyword.iskeyword(user_input):
            break
    return user_input
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always reaching the else statement if the first element in valid_list is not a substring of the user_complaint string. That means you're always breaking out of the for loop and reentering the infinite while loop. Try this instead:

```
def validated_response(user_complaint):
    valid_list = user_complaint.split()
    if user_complaint == "stop":
        return
    inp = input("Enter response: ")
    while inp.lower() not in valid_list:
        inp = input("Enter response: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code has a number of problems. The example does also not show how the function would be called, but I assumed you'd want to call it with a text that has all the keywords you're looking for.

The first problem is you are calling input, but not storing its return value, so you're not actually collecting the user input.

Secondly, you're comparing the various parts of `valid_list` to the contents of `user_complaint.lower()`, but that means you're compare a string to the characters in another string - not what you want.

Thirdly, you're asking for new input in a single clause of a condition, inside your loop, so this will lead to messages printing repeatedly and the user having to enter new text before all the comparisons are done.

Finally, you're mixing `continue`, `break` and `return` in a way that doesn't work. `continue` tells Python to move on to the next cycle of a loop, skipping any remaining code in the current cycle. `break` tells Python to get out of the current block (in this case the loop). `return` tells Python to exit the function altogether and return a provided value (or `None` if none is provided).

Here is an example that more or less follows the structure you set up, but with all of the problems remedied:

```
def validated_response(keywords):
    valid_list = keywords.split()

    while True:
        user_input = input('Enter response: ').lower().split()
        if user_input == ['stop']:
            return False
        for valid in valid_list:
            if valid.lower() in user_input:
                print('response validated: ')
                return True
        print('Response not recognized, please try again')


print(validated_response('trigger test'))
```